# IFC from Cadwork Lexocad to Forge - Multiple PropertySets and Attributes

Tags: autodesk-forge, ifc, autodesk-navisworks

When importing an IFC (2x3 and 4) from Cadwork Lexocad into Forge, several PropertySets and Attributes appear multiple times.

The same thing happens when I open the IFC in Navisworks with the Standard IFC Import settings.
With conversion method: "modern" in navisworks, the PropertySets and Attributes look better, but the geometry gets kind of destroyed (large distance to origin). 
Besides that we would prefer to work with IFC in forge and not with NWD.

When opening the IFC in other Software, that problem does not appear.

I would be thankful for any hints.

This is my result in forge:
[Lexocad IFC to Forge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyZ2d.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Forge Model Derivative service uses Navisworks under the hood when translating IFC files, that would explain why the output you get in Forge Viewer looks the same as in Navisworks. You can try [processing your IFC files with Revit](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-ifc-pipeline-call-change) instead, see if that would make any difference.

Comment: Moreover, if you wouldn't mind sharing the IFC file with us (confidentially) via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, I'd be happy to pass this on to the Model Derivative service engineering team, and have them debug the loader on their end.

Comment: Hey Peter, thank you very much. I will try the Revit-way but would be happy if you could have a look at the ifc that i just sent you, since we would prefer the direct way: Lexocad -> IFC -> Forge

Comment: Did you find time to have a look at the ifc file that i sent you via mail? Would me very much appreciated !

Comment: Hi Jon, unfortunately the feedback from the engineering was that there's no immediate solution for your issue. You can either use the standard IFC importer (with the problematic property naming), or the alternative IFC importer (where the geometry may get distorted due to floating point precision issues). Alternatively, you could try reading the IFC properties yourself using the Forge Design Automation service.